# Netbean GUI interface window closing

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I'm working in the netbeans GUI interface, and I want to know how to close the window.  I found the following code:

```
frame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
```

However, I cannot find the name of the frame in the code.

How do I find the frame name, or am I going about this the wrong way?  How do I close it?

Comment: `JFrame#dispose` or `JFrame#setVisible` would be more preferred. The "name" of the window will be the name of the variable you assigned it to

Comment: Maybe you should start with [How to Make Frames (Main Windows)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html)

Answer (score 1):

Put this line in your form no need to use window event

setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

Answer (score 1):

> How do I close it?

When you create the frame you need code like:

```
Jframe frame = new JFrame(...);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT__ON_CLOSE);
```

Now when you click on the "close" button the application will exit.

However you may also want to close the frame by using a menu item. In this case what you want to do is create an `Action` that you can add to your "Exit" JMenuItem.

Check out the `Exit Action` found in [Closing an Application](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/closing-an-application/). The `Exit Action` shows how you can access the current frame in order to dispatch the windowClosing() event to the frame. So the "Exit" menu item will then function just like the user clicking on the "close" button.

Answer (score 0):

You are using **NetBeans IDE**, go to JFrame Properties, the very first option is ***DefaultCloseOperation***, use the drop down menu to toggle between options available or you can add custom codes.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer at https://netbeans.org/kb/articles/gui-functionality.html

Turns out all I needed was

```
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for :/
It closed the entire programme, not just the JFrame window.